# Script run time difference for code in loop vs code in called function

Tags: python, performance, runtime

I run 2 functions. Both of them have for-loops to execute instructions. Both functions accomplish the same task, but one takes much longer.

Function 1 executes and is self contained, performs TaskA.

```
f1:
  For x in X:
    do task a
```

Function 2 executes and calls Function 3. Function 3 performs TaskA

```
f2:
  For x in X:
    call function 3
f3:
  do task a
```

Why does function 2 generally take 10x as long to execute as function 1?

EDIT: Previous phrasing confused people.

Comment: Well obviously this pseudocode is slow because you're using a terrible pseudocode interpreter... Have you considered posting **actual** code instead?

Comment: You're giving us code where a function call is literally the only difference. The only conclusion we can possibly arrive at is "Function calls are slow". The fact that function calls are not (noticeably) slow in reality shows that you didn't actually post the relevant piece of code. I suggest you try [`cProfile.run('f2()')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another factor could be the "preparation" / setup being done before `TaskA` is called. Possible that in `f1` you've done it once before the `for` loop and then it's done in `f3` so it gets called for every `x in X` from `f2` rather than just once at the beginning. Without any real code, it's hard to say.

As for the potential complexity of calling `f3` for every `x`, it's unlikely that that's the cause of the 10x slowness.

Only in an oversimplified example with `pass` do we see this behaviour. Let's take these 3 bad versions of `f1`, `f2` and `f3`:

```
>>> def f1():
...   for x in X:
...     pass
...
>>> def f2():
...   for x in X:
...     f3()
...
>>> def f3():
...   pass
...
```

Using `dis`, here's what the bytecode looks like for `f1`:

```
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              14 (to 17)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (X)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 16)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3          13 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   16 POP_BLOCK
        >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

...vs `f2`:

```
>>> dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              21 (to 24)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (X)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                13 (to 23)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3          13 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (f3)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             19 POP_TOP
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   23 POP_BLOCK
        >>   24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             27 RETURN_VALUE
```

Those look nearly the same except for the `CALL_FUNCTION` and `POP_TOP`. However, they are very different with `timeit`:

```
>>> X = range(1000)  # [0, 1, 2, ...999]
>>>
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(f1)
10.290941975496747
>>> timeit.timeit(f2)
81.18860785875617
>>>
```

Now that's 8x the time but not because calling a function is *slow* but because doing nothing but `pass` in `f1`'s for loop is *extremely fast*, especially when *calling a function* each time which then does nothing. So hopefully you were **not** using these as examples to find out/wonder why.

Now, if you actually *do something* in the task, like say `x * x` then you'll see the timing/performance difference between the two becomes smaller:

```
>>> def f1():
...   for x in X:
...     _ = x*x
...
>>> def f2():
...   for x in X:
...     _ = f3(x)  # didn't pass in `x` to `f3` in the previous example
...
>>> def f3(x):
...   return x*x
...
>>> timeit.timeit(f1)
38.76545268807092
>>> timeit.timeit(f2)
113.72242594670047
>>>
```

Now that's only **2.9x** the time. It's not the function call which causes the slowness (yes, there is some overhead) but also what you're doing in that function vs `pass` that makes a difference to the overall time.

If you replace the `_ = x * x` with `print x * x` in both places, which is quite "slow", and with just `X = range(5)`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(f1, number=10000)
3.640433839719143
>>> timeit.timeit(f2, number=10000)
3.6921612171574765
```

And now there's much less difference in their performance.

So do an actual check with real code, not just simple pseudocode analysis. Empty calls may appear faster but that overhead is really small compared with the *slower stuff* that code in functions does.

Comment: I really appreciate your in-depth analysis. This is what I was looking for. Sorry if that's generally too much to ask on this board I was unaware.

Comment: The issue is that asking a specific question like yours with no actual code is really hard to answer. So I made up a random example that might explain why you saw such a large performance difference.